# In clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables as follows which has the following attributes:

```
Actor:actor_id,firstname,lastname
film_actor:actor_id,film_id
film_category:film_id,category_id
category:category_id,name
```

I want to find the list of all actors working in films, their film_id, category_id and category name.

I want to use the In clause for foll query. So i am getting the o/p by implementing this as follows:

```
select  a.first_name,a.actor_id,fc.film_id,c.name,c.category_id
from actor a,film_actor fa,film_category fc,category c where a.actor_id 
in (select fa.film_id from film_actor fa where fa.actor_id=a.actor_id
and fa.film_id 
in (select fc.film_id  from film_category fc where fc.film_id=fa.film_id
and fc.category_id 
in(select fc.category_id from category c where c.category_id=fc.category_id)))
```

But suppose now i want to know list of actors for particular category_id.Lets say suppose 5
which is present. So I make following changes:

```
select  a.first_name,a.actor_id,fc.film_id,c.name,c.category_id
from actor a,film_actor fa,film_category fc,category c 
where a.actor_id in 
(select fa.film_id from film_actor fa where fa.actor_id=a.actor_id
and fa.film_id 
in (select fc.film_id  from film_category fc where fc.film_id=fa.film_id
and fc.category_id 
in(select fc.category_id from category c where c.category_id=fc.category_id
and category_id=5)))
```

I am getting empty result.Also lastly when we should use IN clause and when should we not?

Comment: My rule: use IN when comparing with a small number of *values*; use a JOIN otherwise.

Comment: select a.first_name,
  a.actor_id,
  fc.film_id,
  c.name,
  c.category_id
from actor a
left join film_actor fa
  on a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
left join film_category fc
  fa.film_id = fc.film_id
left join category c 
  on fc.category_id = c.category_id
  and c.category_id=5.But this query using joins gives me different result.Why is it so.I mean i am just applying cartesian product

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `IN` for this.. use `JOIN` instead.

```
select  
    a.first_name,
    a.actor_id,
    fc.film_id,
    c.name,
    c.category_id
from 
    actor a join 
    film_actor fa on fa.actor_id = a.actor_id join
    film_category fc on fc.film_id = fa.film_id join
    category c on c.category_id = fc.category_id and c.category_id = 5
```

I typically only use `IN` for a hard-coded set of IDs... `JOIN` or `EXISTS` for every other case.  Not only is this cleaner, but it will likely result in a better performing execution plan as well.

Answer (score 1):

Please start to use join syntax instead of an `IN` clause:

```
select a.first_name,
  a.actor_id,
  fc.film_id,
  c.name,
  c.category_id
from actor a
left join film_actor fa
  on a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
left join film_category fc
  fa.film_id = fc.film_id
left join category c 
  on fc.category_id = c.category_id
  and c.category_id=5
```

This will return all records from the `actor` table regardless of if there is a matching record in the other tables.

If you need help learning `JOIN` syntax here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: ...and instead of old-style implicit joins, blecch!